# Jquery Mobile - Download wont start

Tags: php, jquery, html, mobile

I've got following problem:

I want that the user can click a Button in a HTML Form, then a download starts.

The Button calls a new php file called "working.php" with a POST method.

In the working.php it generates a file and saves it on my server.
After that the customer can download the file.
On the Desktop version, it works, but with JQuery it won't work and I dont know why :(

Here is my Code for index.php:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Mobile</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="styles.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/sl_theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <h1>Mobile</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="#"><img src="../imgs/header.png"/ style="max-width:100%;"></a>
        <form action="../working.php" method="post">
            <input name="sc_url" type="text" size="50" class="textbox"> <br /> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="GO">
        </form>

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>&copy; 2014 by ###</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

and here the code from the working.php

```
    function savefile($id, $title) {
    $dir = "files";
    $file = file_get_contents($id);
    $thetitle = "";
    $titlelen = strlen($title) - 2;
    $thetitle = substr($title, 1, $titlelen);

    $thetitle = str_replace("/", " - ", $thetitle);
    $thetitle = str_replace("\\", " - ", $thetitle);

    if(strlen($thetitle) === 0) {
        die('<html>
                <head>
                    <link href="_styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id=content>Sorry, but I cannot find a Track/Trackname :/ <br /> <br />
                    <a href="index.php" style="text-decoration: underline;">Home</a> </div>
                </body>
            </html>');
    }

    $filename = $dir . "/" . $thetitle . ".mp3";

    file_put_contents("$filename", $file);

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');     
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize("$filename"));
    readfile("$filename");
}
```

When i click the Button, it only shows me a blank page (the working.php), but the download wont start.

Can anyone help me please?

greetings,
pascal

Comment: You should probably post the relevant jQuery as well. And where are you defining `$filename` and `$file`?

Comment: the code is just a short clip of the whole file. but thats not the problem, because it works with normal html/php on a desktop pc.
only with jquery it doesnt work.. :(

Comment: Where exactly are you using jquery?

Comment: @Carlos487: only in the index.php - I dont use it much, i edited the code snippets above

Comment: jQuery mobile tends to use ajax behavior or many of this components, maybe the form is making an ajax post and you need a full page post (refresh) is this running on a website or a phonegap app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile by default use AJAX behavior on forms, a download or an upload to work needs a full post, you should use the attribute

```
data-ajax="false"
```

So the form doesn't use the ajax behavior

```
<form action="../working.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <input name="sc_url" type="text" size="50" class="textbox"> <br /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

If you want to disable globally you shoud use the jquery global object, for more info you could look here:

[Tip: Disable AJAX On jQuery Mobile Forms](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/jquery-mobile/tip-disable-ajax-on-jquery-mobile-forms/)

[jQuery Mobile Forms Demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html)